# Bucles en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un duda, estoy estudiando python y veo una diferencia en la estruturas ciclicas con relacion a las demas.

Cómo hago un programa que imprima números de mayor a menor utilizando el metodo `range()` ?

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar mejor qué deseas imprimir?

Answer (score 0):

Acá tienes algunos ejemplos de cómo utilizar range():

```
#Imprimir de 0 a 9
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
print('\n')

# Imprimir de 10 a 19
for i in range(10,20):
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Imprimir de 0 a 90 (de 10 en 10)
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    print(i)
print('\n')

# Imprimir de 50 a 41
for i in range(50, 40, -1):
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Método burbuja para ordenar una lista de mayor a menor, utilizando range (aunque no es necesario)
lista = [1,56, 12, 54, 78, 20]
for i in range(len(lista)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
        temp = lista[i]
        if lista[i] < lista[j]:
            lista[i] = lista[j]
            lista[j] = temp
print(lista)
```

Comment: No entiendo porque te han puntuado negativamente la respuesta, me parece una muy buena respuesta a la pregunta planteada...

Comment: (No fui yo el del voto). Podrías al menos haber explicado los parámetros que recibe `range` y haber puesto un ejemplo comparativo con opciones similares en C, Java, JS, ...